# how do you connect codeigniter in mssqlserver2012enterprise

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having problem in connecting codeigniter and mssqlserver2012.I used wampp,apatche 2.4.4,phpversion 5.4.16,I already loaded the native client driver by looking in phpinfo(),now the problem is i could not still connect to mssqlserver.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes?but i know that codeigniter can connect to mssqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the mssql db config in your database.php file:

```
$db['mssql']['hostname'] = 'sqlsrv:server=yourserver;database=yourdb;encrypt=true;trustservercertificate=true';
```